# How do I return a dynamically allocated pointer array from a function?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, dynamic

I am now starting Dynamic Memory Allocation in class and have a ok understanding of it but can't completely use it properly. I feel like I may not be so great with pointers either :p

My instructor gave instructions to create a function named readArray that will prompt the user for a number to use as a size to **dynamically** create a integer array of that size. I am then to assign the new array to a pointer. I then am supposed to prompt the user to fill the array. I then am supposed to return both the newly created array and the size.

I can not figure out how to return the array though, and I thought when dynamically allocating memory you were supposed to delete the allocation after using it to prevent leaks.

The array and size must be returned to main so I can pass it to other functions such as a sorting function.

I would greatly appreciate any help I can get as my thought process with this keeps going in the wrong direction.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int* readArray(int&);
void sortArray(int *, const int * );

int main ()
{
   int size = 0;
   int *arrPTR = readArray(size);
   const int *sizePTR = &size;
   sortArray(arrPTR, sizePTR);

   cout<<arrPTR[1]<<arrPTR[2]<<arrPTR[3]<<arrPTR[4];

        system("pause");
        return 0;
}


int* readArray(int &size)
{
   cout<<"Enter a number for size of array.\n";
   cin>>size;
   arrPTR = new int[size];

   for(int count = 0; count < (size-1); count++)
   {    
       cout<<"Enter positive numbers to completely fill the array.\n";
       cin>>*(arrPTR+count);
   }

   return arrPTR;
}
```

Comment: Slight mistake in your example that the prototype of readArray differs from what you have implemented. Although it is not necessary you might also consider giving variable names in the prototypes to aid in documenting what they do.

Comment: You generally don't want to change your example code to match the solution. That is what the answers are for (which then might make no sense when you make updates like this).

Comment: Although most classes on C++ probably cover raw arrays like this pretty early I think it's a bad idea. Beginners should be taught to use vectors, leaving raw arrays and manual dynamic allocation to later in the course as an advanced topic. This is the way Bjarne Stroustrup's wonderful beginner's book [_Programming—Principals and Practice Using C++_](http://www2.research.att.com~bs/programming.html) handles it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To return an array: declare `readArray()` as `int* readArray()` [return an `int*` instead of an `int`], and return `arrPTR` instead of `size`. This way, you return the dynamically allocated array which `arrPTR` points to.

Regarding the delete: When you are done using the array, you should indeed delete it. In your example, do it before `return 0` in your `main()` function.

Make sure that since you allocated memory with `new[]`, you should also free it with [`delete[]`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/new/operator%20delete%5B%5D/), otherwise - your program will have a memory leak.

Comment: Make sure it is deleted using `delete []`

Comment: @Vyktor: This is homework, I only gave him hints how to do it, if I do what you are suggesting, he will not learn from it.

Comment: @Joe: you are 100% correct. What seems trivial to us, is not for beginners. I will edit my answer and add it.

Comment: @amit I have done what you said and edited my code up top but I still am having problems.  on  `int *arrPTR = readArray(size);`                                                readArray has the error _"more than one instance of overloaded function "readArray" matches the argument list."_

Comment: Nevermind I forgot a reference variable in my function declaration :p

Answer (score 6):

You would not need to do that if you use `std::vector<int>` which is far superior choice.

Use it:

```
std::vector<int> readArray()
{
    int size = 0;
    cout<<"Enter a number for size of array.\n";
    cin >> size;
    std::vector<int> v(size);

    cout<<"Enter "<< size <<" positive numbers to completely fill the array : ";
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {   
        cin>> v[i];
    }
    return v;
}
```

Comment: This would be the perfect solution but it seems they should study `new` operator usage right now, mentioning vectors (and other containers) may be confusing. IMHO.

Comment: Yes it is a better solution, but should he *not* understand what the teacher is trying to teach?

Comment: I haven't learned about vectors yet and the assignment is very specific on using pointers and the new operator.

Comment: The question as posed implies the usage of this might not be an acceptable solution though. even though it is a good one.

Comment: About edit: isn't that slow solution? It'll probably allocate `size` ints (`v(size)`), than reallocate it (`size = readArray()`) and finally delete `v)... Much faster would be `readArray( vector<int> &target)`

Comment: @Vyktor: You're surely unaware of RVO : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization  ... and move-semantic introduced by C++11.

Comment: @Vyktor: A C++11 compiler will return the vector by moving it; a decent C++03 compiler will elide the copy.

Comment: This is the way C++ courses _should_ be taught. Although most classes on C++ probably cover raw arrays like this pretty early it's a mistake. Beginners should be taught to use vectors, treating raw arrays and manual dynamic allocation as an advanced topic. Bjarne Stroustrup's beginner's book [_Programming—Principals and Practice Using C++_](http://www2.research.att.com~bs/programming.html) does this correctly.

Comment: @bames53: "*Although most classes on C++ probably cover raw arrays*" which is sad!

Comment: This is the truth and I feel like we are blowing through all of this way too fast in class.

Comment: @bames53: I disagree. In university, the goal of teaching basics c++ is not only "to use c++ properly". One of the goals of these courses is also that the students will understand memory allocations [automatic/dynamic], the difference between reference variables and value variables, memory layout, .... Understanding those concepts usually require some dirty work with dynamic array allocations and using pointers [to pointers to pointers...]

Comment: @amit: Teaching `new`, `delete`, and *raw arrays* are NOT basics. They're pretty much advanced. Basic of C++ are functions, loops, branching (i.e if-else etc), different kinds of variables and their lifetimes, and standard containers and algorithms. Once you're done with them, only then I think one should start reading memory allocation, deallocations, techniques related to them (such as RAII), raw arrays, etc.

Comment: I would go the extra distance and learn both. Submit both, and understand why `vector` is superior. You're not there to please the University, you're there to learn about the problems of trying to teach Computer Science. Read [Zen and the Art of Motorcycle Maintenance](http://www.bartneck.de/projects/research/pirsig/)

Comment: @Nawaz: The word "basics" was missleading, my intent was: [in my opinion] the introduction courses in university **does not** aim to teach you how to master c++, they aim to teach you important *computer science* concepts, such as those I mentioned. They achieve this via using c/c++ and enforcing you to use these methods.

Comment: @amit: Teach them Assembly then. Would it be a good choice in these days? Before C, assembly was the language they used to teach, but when C came into being, they forgot assembly and started teaching C, as it produces the same result they used to get from assembly. Likewise, now C++ has come, it is pretty much mature from many angles, so they should teach C++, (not C, disguised as C++)

Comment: @amit "they aim to teach you important _computer science_ concepts." I agree and I believe this implies that they should begin with `vector` rather than manual arrays. Note that Bjarne Stroustrup elected to teach his C++ courses this way. I think he's right because programming at that level means you can focus on the computer science and not on the intricacies of how arrays in C are special and what you need to do in C++ to make manual `new`/`delete` exception safe. Those are advanced topics for mastering the language, and they take you further away from algorithms and abstract program design.

Comment: @bames53, Nawaz: I think we can agree to disagree here. This discussion is very subjective and there are good arguments to both approaches.

Answer (score 1):

Like amit says, you should probably return the array instead of size. But since you still need the size, change `readArray` like so:

```
///return array (must be deleted after)
///and pass size by reference so it can be changed by the function
int* readArray(int &size);
```

and call it like this:

```
int size = 0;
int *arrPTR = readArray(size);
///....Do stuff here with arrPTR
delete arrPTR[];
```

After update:

```
int* readArray(int size); ///input only! need the & in the declaration to match
                          ///the function body!
```

Is wrong, since you have your actual definition with the `int &size`.
You also don't declare `arrPTR` in `readArray`, just assign it.