# Function works without deleting the dynamic array. Program works and has no errors

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic, delete-operator

I am a student and a beginner in C++.In class we are practicing pointers, dynamic arrays and functions at the moment. I wrote a program that has no errors and does what it has to do. My problem is that it works without deleting the dynamic array. **we were asked to put the delete[] inside the function**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

char* Function (char c[], int numbers[]){
    int k=0;

    for ( int i=0; i< 4;i++){
        k+=numbers[i];
    }

    k++;
    char *result = new char[k];
    char *counter=result;

    for ( int i=0; c[i]!='\0';i++)
    {
        int index = numbers[i];

        for (int j=0; j< index; j++)
        {
            *counter=c[i];
            counter=counter+1;
        }
     }

     *counter='\0';

     return result;

 }

int main ()
{
    char c[]="abcd";
    int numbers []={1,2,3,4};
    char d[]="ghj";
    int numbersx []={2,1,1};

    cout << Function(c,numbers);
    cout << Function(d,numbersx);

    return 0;   
 }
```

It is unclear to me where the delete[] would be positioned in this case. 
I have searched [this recommends that i put the delete inside main](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9314089/how-do-i-return-a-dynamically-allocated-pointer-array-from-a-function)
other answers don't answer my exact question.

Comment: It is suggested as a good practice.  It case of small arrays, it doesn't make any difference; however for large arrays, you need to use it so as to free up the memory.

Comment: Oh ok, I am either way confused about where the delete should be placed

Comment: It is usually placed in the end, when you no longer need the array.

Comment: yeah, but if I put it after the return will it still be deleted? It has to be placed in the function and not in main.

Comment: If you put `delete []` inside `main` then it will work fine. If you put `delete[]` inside `Function` but before `return` then in this case you will be returning a pointer (`return result;`) which points to deleted memory and in then `main` you will be accessing deleted memory which will have undefined behavior. So if you want to put `delete []` inside 'Function' and yet want to access the `result` in  `main` then create a copy of memory pointed to by `result` and return it from `Function`.  Memory won't be deleted if you write `delete[]` after return in `Function`.

Comment: @Igna: Your teacher is using outdated methods. This technique went out of style in the 20th century. In this century, we just write `std::string Function(std::string letters, std::vector<int> numbers)`. That allows you to just write `std::string result`, without `new[]` and therefore also without `delete[]`. And you wouldn't need to care about `k` either.

Comment: I.e : `std::string Function(std::string letters, std::vector<int> numbers) { std::string result; for (int i = 0; i != letters.size(); ++i) { result += std::string(numbers[i], letters[i]); } return result; }`. DONE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My problem is that it works without deleting the dynamic array.

It might work... but it also leaks memory. Memory leaks are a bad thing on computers that don't have unlimited memory.

> It is unclear to me where the delete[] would be positioned in this case.

It must be positioned so that the pointed object is never *used* after it has been deleted. *Using* here means accessing  the memory of the object for example by dereferencing a pointer to it.

> if I put it after the return will it still be deleted?

If you mean that it was in `Function` but after return, then of course not. Nothing in the function is executed after returning.

> It has to be placed in the function and not in main.

If you were to delete in `Function`, then you would be returning a pointer to a deleted object, which would be very bad. I recommend giving up this silly requirement.

Technically, `main` never dereferences the pointer, so the program would still technically have well defined behaviour even if you did delete in `Function`, even though the return value of would then be completely useless.

Comment: @KarstenKoop Correct.

Answer (score 0):

It's ok to delete it inside a function. Just don't free/delete it again. You can also delete it in `main()`.

You don't have visible problems if you don't delete it (the compiler won' complain, nor will the program crash). You will however have memory leaks, and that's most definitely not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't free the memory, you will end up with memory leaks. For simple applications like this, you're unlikely to see a problem. For larger / longer-running applications where you're allocating a lot of data before the application exits, you will eventually run out of memory and the program will crash and/or your operating system will slow to a crawl as it pages data to disk.

To free the memory but still print some output you would need something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void Function (char c[], int numbers[]){
    int k=0;

    for ( int i=0; i< 4;i++){
        k+=numbers[i];
    }

    k++;
    char *result = new char[k];
    char *counter=result;

    for ( int i=0; c[i]!='\0';i++)
    {
        int index = numbers[i];

        for (int j=0; j< index; j++)
        {
            *counter=c[i];
            counter=counter+1;
        }
    }

    *counter='\0';

    cout << result;

    delete [] result;
 }

int main ()
{
    char c[]="abcd";
    int numbers []={1,2,3,4};
    char d[]="ghj";
    int numbersx []={2,1,1};

    Function(c,numbers);
    Function(d,numbersx);

    return 0;   
}
```

That's the only way you could get the `delete[]` inside your function because as others have said, you still need to access the memory to report the result after the function has returned.

The alternative would be to call `delete []` twice in the main method as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

char* Function (char c[], int numbers[]){
    int k=0;

    for ( int i=0; i< 4;i++){
        k+=numbers[i];
    }

    k++;
    char *result = new char[k];
    char *counter=result;

    for ( int i=0; c[i]!='\0';i++)
    {
        int index = numbers[i];

        for (int j=0; j< index; j++)
        {
            *counter=c[i];
            counter=counter+1;
        }
    }

    *counter='\0';

    return result;
}

int main ()
{
    char c[]="abcd";
    int numbers []={1,2,3,4};
    char d[]="ghj";
    int numbersx []={2,1,1};

    char* result = Function(c,numbers);
    cout << result;
    delete[] result;

    result = Function(d,numbers);
    cout << result;
    delete[] result;

    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: @Igna: Look at the this part of code "To free the memory but still print some output you would need something like this". Your teacher might be expecting this.